# TestCafe being able to select a disabled checkbox

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

Lately, I'm encountering a small issue with the latest Chrome version and Testcafe 1.3.3.
In one of the test scripts I have, I'm trying to see, if I can select a checkbox, that it's disabled. Off course, this shouldn't happen, but, it still does.

The front end to recreated the test page is:
[image]

The test script executed in Testcafe is:

```
...
checkboxDisabledInput = Selector('#input-2');
...

fixture
...
test('Expect disabled checkbox is visible and cannot be selected/checked;', async () => {
await t
    .expect(checkboxDisabledInput.checked).eql(false)
    .click(checkboxDisabledInput)
    .expect(checkboxDisabledInput.checked).eql(false);
```

When I'm executing this test on Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) the checkbox is being selected, even if if a disabled field shouldn't allow this kind of interaction. 
The funny part is that me as a user, in a manual way, can't select the checkbox under no circumstances.

```
 AssertionError: expected true to deeply equal false
  Browser: Chrome 75.0.3770 / Windows 10.0.0
     38 |test('Expect disabled checkbox is visible and cannot be selected/checked;', async () => {
     39 |    await t
     40 |        .expect(checkboxField.checkboxDisabledInput.visible).eql(true)
     41 |        .expect(checkboxField.checkboxDisabledInput.checked).eql(false)
     42 |        .click(checkboxField.checkboxDisabledInput)
   > 43 |        .expect(checkboxField.checkboxDisabledInput.checked).eql(false);
```

If I execute the above test under the exact same scenario, but on Firefox browser, I can't reproduce the selection of the disabled checkbox anymore.

Therefore, my presumption is that there is a bug while using the above version of Chrome and TestCafe.
**Is there someone else having this problem?**

Comment: Could you provide a simplified project so that we will reproduce this behavior? A similar project works properly with the checkbox like <input type="checkbox" disabled> on my side.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't provide more than what I already posted, because it's an internal web page and it's not public, and furthermore, I don't have access to the elements classes..

Answer (score 3):

This issue might be related to the following problem: [Click event on label should be prevented if its child input element is disabled](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/1931). Please track our progress with it and try our fix.

Comment: great, could be! 10x!